# Android : onOptionsItemSelected getItemId returns wrong id

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to link actionBar menu items to swipe pages using FragmentPagerAdapter when each icon is clicked, but then, item.getItemId() returns a very weird number instead of 1-5 number since I only have 5 pages.

I have the following in the main activity class after onCreate :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(id);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

I get a number like, **2131624103**, where the last digit(3) is the page number.

Is this a normal behaviour? How do I do this?

Comment: you need to pass position in setCurrentItem not in id!!

Comment: So, you can use switch case in this case

Comment: @NiravRanpara, How do i get position? Its in another class that extends FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: `item.getItemId()` returns the ID of the item, if you compare that to the ID of one of the options you can quickly find out if that is the selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass postition in setCurrentItem and use switch case for this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.one:
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Makes sense now, I thought menuItem.getItemId() returns position, I don't know where I got that idea either.